# What am I doing wrong with my template syntax?

Tags: c++, templates

So I'm working on porting a library from C#/XNA to C++/SDL and I'm kind of inexperienced in C++. I'm trying to rewrite some generic data containers, but I'm getting weird errors with the template syntax. I've looked at lots of examples but I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm working in the Code Blocks IDE. Here is my code and the error messages Code Blocks is giving me. It seems to be not recognizing what the template name is supposed to be.

```
template <typename T>
class DataGrid
{
    private:
        int width;
        int height;
        T[ , ] data;
    public:
        DataGrid(int, int);
        ~DataGrid();
        void setData(int, int, T);
        T getData(int, int);
        bool inDomain(int, int);
        bool isValidPoint(int, int);
        void formatBoard(int, int);
};

#include "DataGrid.h"

//template <typename T>
DataGrid::DataGrid(int w, int h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    data = new T[width, height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            data[i, k] = default(T);
        }
    }
}
//template <typename T>
DataGrid::~DataGrid()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            delete data[i, k];
        }
    }
    delete data;
}
//template <typename T>
T DataGrid::getData(int x, int y)
{
    if (inDomain(x, y))
    {
        return data[x, y];
    }
}
template <typename T>
void DataGrid::setData(int x, int y, T &nData)
{
   if (inDomain(x, y))
   {
       data[x, y] = nData;
   }
}
//template <typename T>
bool DataGrid::inDomain(int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < width)
    {
        if (y >= 0 && height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
//template <typename T>
bool DataGrid::isValidPoint(int x, int y)
{
    if (inDomain(x, y))
    {
        if (data[x, y] != default(T))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
//template <typename T>
void DataGrid::formatBoard(int width, int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            delete data[i, k];
        }
    }
    delete data;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++)
        {
            data[i, k] = default(T);
        }
    }
}
//template <typename T>
int DataGrid::getWidth()
{
    return width;
}
//template <typename T>
int DataGrid::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}
```

The following are the errors

> error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
>
> error: invalid use of template-name 'DataGrid' without argument list
>
> error: 'T' does not name a type
>
> error: 'template class DataGrid' used without template parameters

Comment: `T[ , ] data` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: As an aside, your test functions are unnecessarily complex.They can be greatly simplified. e.g. `bool DataGrid::inDomain(int x, int y) { return x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height; }`

Answer (score 1):

When you define the member functions of a class template outside the definition of the class template, you need to use the following syntax:

```
template <typename T> // Need this
DataGrid<T>::DataGrid(int w, int h) { ... }
    //  ^^^ Need this also.
```

and

```
template <typename T>
DataGrid<T>::~DataGrid() { ... }
```